# MacOs kernel-userspace communication using file

Tags: linux, macos, linux-kernel, kernel, mach

I want to create a file from kernel and this file must be accessed from user space. Other ways of communication (for example ioctl) is not suitable, because the user space application needs only files, and I don't have the source code of it.

I need to do this on MAC. If I were using Linux, I would use sysfs for it, but on MacOs they dont have sysfs, so I decided to end up with devfs

I created the sample soultion and everything works great, but the problem is that the device file (devfs file) does not have size. The user-space code checks for file size and skips this file. I know how big the size will be, but I dont know how to set it to devfs file.

I dont want to create the file in real filesystem, because it can be quite big. All I want is to redirect reads and writes to my internal functions.

FUSE (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) would be ideal for be, but this involves user-space daemon.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming you're developing a kext? Is there a specific reason why the file must be created in the kernel? Alternatively you could pass data from the kernel to a user space program and have it create the file.

Comment: Yes, I am developing a kernel extension. generally, creating the file in using space using FUSE can be ok, I am just trying not to involve new layers - daemon that will create file, and FUSE libabry

Comment: Oh, I see, you're just creating a kext and don't have a daemon.